# Create storage profile for launching Azure VM via Ruby

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-for-ruby

I'm trying to create/delete VMs in Azure cloud using [azure-sdk-for-ruby](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby). I'm following the example in the [compute API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/tree/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute#creating-new-virtual-machine).

There is one part that I can't understand:

```
# create_storage_profile is hypothetical helper method which creates storage
# profile by means of ARM Storage SDK.
params.storage_profile = create_storage_profile
```

How would I go about creating a profile for the new VM?

I've looked through the [storage API](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/azure_mgmt_storage), but I didn't find anything.

Comment: This really seems to be asking for code or explanation that can reasonably be shared on SO, rather than a link to a tutorial or code-dump collection site.

Comment: I see zero reason for this to be on hold. The question is not asking for code to be written but for a strategy that is not evident in documentation.

Comment: I'll vote to reopen just as soon as the question includes the *complete* code which OP is having difficulty with (and not just a snippet of it + link to offsite resource - those are banned).

Comment: Being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348053/692942).

Comment: The answer is in the code comment, it's a *hypothetical* helper method. In other words build your own helper method to create a [`StorageProfile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/models/storage_profile.rb) see `def create_storage_profile` in [virtual_machines_spec.rb](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/spec/virtual_machines_spec.rb).

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I don't code Ruby but I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424579/create-storage-profile-for-launching-azure-vm-via-ruby#comment74080154_43424579) in less than 5 minutes on Google.

Comment: @Lankymart, hmm, I grepped through these files but obviously I missed this one somehow. The storage profile creation bits are indeed inside the linked spec. Good catch.

Comment: wrt comment about 5 minutes search - this seems to be a link to my question ;) but missing the storage creation in the spec file was indeed a  on me and you did a good job spotting it.

Comment: @akostadinov the link was back to my previous comment, sorry for the confusion *(it should have reloaded the page and highlighted the relevant comment orange)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an offical [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/compute-ruby-manage-vm/blob/master/example.rb) for create a Azure VM using Azure SDK for Ruby, which you can find the code you want about `create_storage_profile` and `create_network_profile` via the keywords `storage_profile`, `storage_account`, `network_profile` and `create_vm`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: wow, didn't spot that one, thank you. It also has a linux config example which is the other missing piece.

Comment: btw I would appreciate if you explain why did you voted this question for closing.

Comment: Yes, answering and voting to close is usually frowned upon. If you feel the question is off-topic, it should not be answered.

Comment: @Lankymart see my meta comment, this is a completely different repo from the SDK repo and I don't see it linked from the SDK docs. Please check facts before posting hard conclusions everywhere.

Comment: @akostadinov Means nothing, [see my meta comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348053/how-is-this-off-topic#comment467072_348053).

Comment: @Lankymart, I have replied to you in meta. I would suggest to stick to one place for discussing - be it meta or here.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly the RubyDocs aren't great, but just searching on `ruby storage_profile` was more than helpful.

The `def` for `create_storage_profile` can be found in [virtual_machines_spec.rb](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/spec/2017-03-30/virtual_machines_spec.rb)

```
def create_storage_profile
  storage_profile = StorageProfile.new
  storage_profile.image_reference = get_image_reference
  storage = create_storage_account
  os_disk = OSDisk.new
  os_disk.caching = 'None'
  os_disk.create_option = 'fromImage'
  os_disk.name = 'Test'
  virtual_hard_disk = VirtualHardDisk.new
  virtual_hard_disk.uri = generate_os_vhd_uri storage.name
  os_disk.vhd = virtual_hard_disk
  storage_profile.os_disk = os_disk
  storage_profile
end
```

You don't necessarily need that either as the code snippet stated, it's a *hypothetical* helper method. It just needs a method to return a [`StorageProfile`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/management/azure_mgmt_compute/lib/2018-06-01/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/models/storage_profile.rb) instance.

Comment: +1 for spotting the correct spec file. I missed that. Keeping Peter's answer as accepted as it is much richer. btw `get_image_reference` method also needs to be pasted into the answer to be complete as it contains vital bits.

Comment: @akostadinov *"much richer"*? Hmm...agree to disagree. As for including other code, there will be all sorts of references missing but that is the `def` for `create_storage_profile` I'm sure once people know where to look, the rest of the references can be worked out. To be honest didn't want to answer, but felt it was the only way to show how pointless this question is.

Comment: I agree with you. I thought you're trying to paste a completely working snippet. To me the reference to the file is good enough. `get_image_reference` method is vital part of `create_storage_profile`. Not important for me. Just a nit pick. wrt richer answer - there are more examples. But your answer is nonetheless complete and appreciated.

Comment: @Lankymart, The [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43424579/timeline) shows answer posted, then question closed > a day later. Given we don't see when close votes are placed, only when the close happens, we can't know when PerterPan voted to close wrt. when the answer was posted. However, PerterPan's close vote was the second one placed, but the first vote/flag was clearly prior to the answer, based on entering review queue. If the goal was to highlight that it needed to be closed, that's what comments are for. I note that you *also* answered and voted to close, for the second closure.